# Xamarin.Forms layout with buttons while entry is focused

Tags: android, ios, autocomplete, xamarin.forms, textinput

I want to create a simple layout which holds buttons, that will be visible and clickable under an entry, as long as the entry is focused. Clicking any of the buttons should not unfocus the entry.

I tried to do it with 2 separate views (entry + layout (grid) with buttons).
But clicking any of the buttons would unfocus the entry and therefore hide my layout.

In android I found out a workaround by setting a Task.Yield into the clickhandler of each button, on iOS this does not work, as I have to bind to the TouchBegin events on the native Control, but they do not give me the opportunity to delay the actual click.

Do you guys have any ideas?

Either a basic approach for iOS or for a Xamarin.Forms version would be greatly appreciated (C#/swift/objective-c, etc. ... doesn't matter!)

Comment: Not clear what you said , could you add some code to describe your issue?

Comment: A layout that expands while an entry is focused, like an autocompleteview,but hitting buttons of the layout shouldnt close the layout